# How to do Google Sign-In in Meteor

Tags: authentication, meteor, iron-router

I've tried various tutorials and links on how to get Google Sign-In to work in Meteor to no avail. How can I create a google sign in button on my login page that redirects to my user dashboard--using iron:router perhaps (and shows the persons name in the corner), and restrict the google emails to only .edu accounts?

Also as the admin of the page how would I be able to see the emails/names of all the people who have logged into my website? Is this done through Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **For Google Sign-in**, I would recommend installing the [accounts-entry](https://atmospherejs.com/joshowens/accounts-entry) package and configuring it from your browser:

  install with latest meteor version

  `meteor add joshowens:accounts-entry`

  and for meteor version before 0.9 use

  `mrt add accounts-entry`
- **For your dashboard redirection**, [review the documentation for that package on atmospherejs.com](https://atmospherejs.com/joshowens/accounts-entry) which demonstrates how to configure your dashboardRoute:

  `dashboardRoute: '/dashboard'`
- **The iron-router package** is a dependency of accounts-entry, so it will be installed as well.
- **Access the data** by launching the MongoDB shell (after starting your app):

  `meteor mongo`
- **Query for the accounts** using the MongoDB shell:

  `db.users.find()`
- **This is not handled via Google Analytics**

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the **accounts-google** package. You'll need to configure the Google sign in with the application *key* and *secret*. The easiest way to do this is to also add the **accounts-ui** package and using 
    `{{> loginButtons}}` 
which will display detailed instructions on the steps to follow on the Google page. It will also save your app key and secret tokens appropriately.

Once this is done you'll be okay using the method 
    `Meteor.loginWithGoogle()` 
as explained in the docs. It takes an optional array of options and a callback function

e.g

```
Meteor.loginWithGoogle({}, function(error){
     if(error)
         //Couldn't log in
     else
         Router.go('/dashboard');
})
```

Good luck